# How do people find just raw audio from a song?

Tags: audio, vocals, phase, phase-alignment

I have found a lot of youtube videos and the like that have just the raw vocals from a song (sometimes called the acapella version). The quality often sounds like it has these remnants so it sounds like they are ripping the vocals from the original song. My general understanding is that this has something to do with phase cancellation, can anybody provide more information on how to do this?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The OP is asking about the phase inversion technique, which is explicitly excluded from the linked question from Tetsujin. Some people may want to learn, try and understand the "old technique".

Comment: This answers that question anyway https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/23374/subtracting-specific-audio-using-an-isolated-track-from-the-same-mix